# SharePoint 2013 DataSheet View make Column mandatory

Tags: client-side-rendering, datasheet, quick-edit

I am currently trying to make a specific Column mandatory on SharePoint Datasheet View.
SharePoint default validation on Column or List Level are NOT an option.

I allready have the Code to check for the right view GUID and so on, but I can't find any hint on how to make a specific Column mandatory in a specific view.

I would be happy if I could insert the JS later on the Masterpage Level, but it would be also okay if it works via js Link.

I have tried for days now but I don't find the right point....

I hope it is understandable what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with customizing the particular list in infopath designer, make certain fields based on your requirement conditionally using the infopath rules.... this is very simple to implement than going with the coding approach.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info!
I will have a look at this, but to be onest, I didn't work with infopath designer jet.

Comment: As far as I understand, InfoPath doesn't work with the datasheet/ quickedit view?
So sadly, this doesnt help...

Comment: When we are applying conditional rules for mandatory columns, it does not matter in which view we are opening this as this works on the column level :-)  try this first in your test server.

Comment: Sorry to ask again:
But isnt this the same as list item validation?
Can I go there and say: If viewGUID = XYZ, Field  "myfield" = required?
Because I cannot only make a Field required based only on other Field Inputs.